# Multiple pattern match and replace

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

How to extract patterns from a file  and replace the multiple patterns with a new pattern from a file?
For example:
Lets say the pattern file is pattern.txt, as follows with 2,000 lines.

```
a  
b   
d  
e  
f  
....  
...  
...
```

File to replace pattens is replace.txt  containing:

```
a,1    
b,3  
c,5  
d,10  
e,14   
....  
...  
...
```

The intended final file content for file patterns.txt is:

```
a,1    
b,3    
d,10  
e,14  
....  
...  
...
```

Comment: Is this proper csv? Can it contain quoted commas and spaces and odd characters, such as `"foo bar", "a,b,c,d", "&auml;åäö"`?

Comment: Yes, it is a proper csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -i -pe'
  BEGIN{ local (@ARGV, $/, $^I) =pop; %h = split /[\s,]+/, <> }
  s| (\S+)\K |,$h{$1}|x
' pattern.txt replace.txt
```

It slurps content of second file (`$/` to undef), and temporarily disables in-place editing (`$^I` to undef), splits string on white-spaces/commas and populate `%h` hash in key/value manner. Then for every line of first file adds comma and value for current key.

Comment: `(\w+)` will fail for lines such as `foo bar` or `?query=foo&bar=baz`

Comment: A lot more concise than the one I was putting together. Although I suppose that isn't always a good thing...

Comment: @Sobrique yes, that is true.

Comment: @TLP I was referring to original input.

Comment: Well, the original input looks like placeholders to me. As far as we know, it is arbitrary strings.

Comment: @TLP how about `(.+)`?

Comment: I was testing something along the lines `([^,]+)`, but now I am wondering if the most correct way is not to use `Text::CSV`.

Answer (score 2):

With the possibility of arbitrary characters in your input, it might be safest to use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). The benefit is that it will handle things like quoted delimiters, multiline strings, etc. The drawback is that it can break on non-csv content, so it sort of relies on your input being proper csv.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        binary => 1,
        eol => $/,
    });
my %s;
my ($input, $replace) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $replace or die "Cannot open $replace: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my ($key, $line) = @$row;
    $s{$key} = $line;
}

open $fh, "<", $input or die "Cannot open $input: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, [$_, $s{$_}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this really needs a regex as you're not really altering your source, as much as 'just' printing based on key fields.

So I would approach it something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $replace, "<", "replace.txt" ) or die $!;

my %replacements;
while (<$replace>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $key, $value ) = split(/,/);
    $replacements{$key} = $value;
}
close($replace);

open( my $input,  "<", "input.txt" )    or die $!;
open( my $output, ">", "patterns.txt" ) or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $replacements{$line} ) {
        print {$output} $replacements{$line}, "\n";
    }
}

close($input);
close($output);
```

It's not as concise as some of the other examples, but hopefully clearer what it's actually doing. This I call a good thing. (I can make it much more compact, in the way that `perl` is (in)famous for).